# Nautilus error (no visible problems)

Tags: nautilus, crash

I got an error message saying "Sorry, Ubuntu has experienced
 an internal error".

[More details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Asv.png)

Comment: And what do you want to do about it?

Comment: It's just worrying me.

Comment: What Ubuntu version? This was fixed in 15.10 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1283426

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop

Comment: Try upgrading then.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: It happens if you rename or move a file with a thumbnail associated, it is supposedly  thumblered that causes the problem, when the file or folder suddenly disappears (the rename or move) when it is creating thumbnail for the file!

Comment: I haven't renamed or moved ANY files.

Comment: By upgrading they mean go to 16.04. Pretty severe reaction to something that happens rarely for most. Maybe run this is a terminal to remove any apport crash reports & likely you won't see that message for some time. `sudo rm /var/crash/*.*`  (- I'd strongly suggest copy & paste if deciding to use command to avoid typing wrong

Comment: I know how to upgrade: _sudo apt-get upgrade_

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu  a lot of errors which are most of the time not a problem. Just don't worry about them until you see something strange. Those errors are automatically corrected by Ubuntu.